# Flutter Background Service not Stopping when App is removed from Task Manager

Tags: flutter, background-service, flutter-background

After starting the background service and removing the app from the task manager.After again opening the app and trying to stop the service using the button. It does not work.
Although It Shows the Service is Running.
I have also tried using AppLifecycleState.detached still it does stops the service If I try to stop the service on AppLifecycleState.paused it works fine

```
case AppLifecycleState.detached:
    print('appLifeCycleState detached');
    FlutterBackgroundService().invoke("stopService");
    break;
```

Comment: did you find some solution?Currently similar issue i am facing

Comment: No, I tried various such as WidgetsBindingObserver But Any of them didn't work. Still Looking for solution

Comment: I'm facing the same issue now, have you found any probable workaround?